# pointer parameter corrupted: returning the pointer or passing address of pointer works

Tags: c, pointers, parameters

I'm passing a pointer to a user-defined type to a function that `malloc`'s memory and sets this pointer to point to it. `malloc()` comes back with a pointer, but when I return from the function, my pointer is clobbered.  I came up with a couple of fixes:

- return the pointer instead of passing it
- pass the address of the pointer rather than the pointer itself

I suspect this is akin to the case with `FILE` pointers; if you pass the pointer to a function, you can't count on the pointer not being changed because the system may fiddle with it. So you pass the address of the `FILE *` instead.

Anyone have an explanation for this?  Here's the code (sorry, it's a bit long):

```
typedef struct  {
    BOOK *bookAry;
    int numBooks;
}INVENTORY;
```

I had this in `main()`, where `INVENTORY` is a user-defined type as above:

```
//variable declarations
INVENTORY *inv = NULL;

//process
initInventory( inv, bookArySize );
processFile( inv );
```

The `initInventory()` function is as follows:

```
void initInventory( INVENTORY *inv, int size ) {

    //process
    inv = ( INVENTORY * ) malloc( sizeof( INVENTORY ) );
       //more code here....
    return;

}//initInventory
```

So we return to `main()` (we think) with `inv` pointing to the newly-allocated memory (and `inv` points to a struct that has other pointers).  Only when I pass the pointer `inv` to `processFile()`, it's been clobbered, and when I try to reference the data in the `inventory` struct, I get an access violation. It turns out the pointer's invalid on return to `main()`!

This fixed it: `main()` has:

```
//variable declarations
INVENTORY *inv = NULL;

//process
inv = initInventory( inv, bookArySize );
processFile( inv );
```

and `initInventory()` is changed to this:

```
INVENTORY * initInventory( INVENTORY *inv, int size ) {

    //process
    inv = ( INVENTORY * ) malloc( sizeof( INVENTORY ) );


    //return a pointer to the INVENTORY header struct
    return inv;

}//initInventory
```

Then I tried this, which I think is a better fix. `main()` now has:

```
//variable declarations
INVENTORY *inv = NULL;
    //more code here...

//process
initInventory( &inv, bookArySize );
processFile( inv );
```

And `initInventory()` is as follows:

```
void initInventory( INVENTORY **inv, int size ) {

    //process
    *inv = ( INVENTORY * ) malloc( sizeof( INVENTORY ) );
        //more code here....
    return;

}//initInventory
```

Comment: arguments, in C, are passed by value, always, all types of parameters. So when you pass `inv` really you pass the value of `inv`, namely `NULL`. Then, inside the function, that value is assigned to the *local* `inv` variable, which you can change at your hearts content.

Answer (score 0):

What you do here:

```
void initInventory( INVENTORY *inv, int size ) {

    //process
    inv = ( INVENTORY * ) malloc( sizeof( INVENTORY ) );
    //more code here....
    return;

}//initInventory
```

is basically this: You pass a copy of the address as a parameter and then change the copy. It has the same affect as assigning something to `size` inside that function: It just changes the local copy.

Your "fixes" are the two correct solutions: Either pass in a pointer to the variable which you want to change (and in this case it's a pointer to a pointer) or return the pointer of the malloc.

btw: You should not cast the return value of malloc. You gain nothing and hide potential problems. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: I was always taught to cast the return from malloc, but the thread you pointed to has a good point.  Thanks for the explanation and the link.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you pass in a pointer by value, it is copied into the parameter and the caller pointer cannot be changed by the called function - the malloc() assigns to the passed parameter OK, but this change to the copy is lost upon return from the function - *INV remains NULL.  Explicitly returning the pointer, or passing in the pointer by reference, (**), are both fine - the pointer returned by malloc() is loaded into the callers variable and so can be successfully dereferenced by the caller after the return.

It is the same issue as FILE pointers.  If you intend to open the file inside the called function and access it in the caller after return, you cannot pass in the FILE* by value.

Comment: Line 4 in the above answer should have had two asterisks in the round brackets.  I typed in two *, but for some reason, the answer seems to contain only one.  I cannot seem to enter two *.  Some isue with the stackoverflow page script??

Comment: @Martin: try backslash asterisk ( \\* ): asterisks are used for italic and bold, using backslash makes them "normal"

Comment: two stars is the start of **bold** - you may have to escape them with back-slash or wrap with back-quote (as code).

Comment: Of course!!!!  If you want to change something in the calling function, you pass in a pointer to that thing.  In this case, the thing is a pointer, so I've got to pass a pointer to it - thus, INVENTORY **  If I'd just wanted to change what the 'inv' pointer points to, passing 'inv' would have done the job.  I guess I intuitively knew what to do but hadn't yet verbalized it.  Thanks so much for the explanations.

Comment: Best Christmas cheer, (and a couple comment votes), to pmg and kfmfe04 for explaining the asterisk issue with the page.